# Grafana Dashboard for Gatling-influxdb Setup

Tags: grafana, gatling, grafana-variable, grafana-templating, flux-influxdb

I am trying to import some readymade dashboard from grafana for my setup( gatling/influxdb) but those are not working somehow specially simulation parameter in grafana dashboard.if someone using same setup , can please share their json file.

below is my config for gatling and influxdb

gatling.conf

```html
data {
    writers = [console,file,graphite]      # The list of DataWriters to which Gatling write simulation data (currently supported : console, file, graphite)
    console {
      light = false                # When set to true, displays a light version without detailed request stats
      writePeriod = 5              # Write interval, in seconds
    }
    file {
      bufferSize = 8192            # FileDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
    }
    leak {
      noActivityTimeout = 30  # Period, in seconds, for which Gatling may have no activity before considering a leak may be happening
    }
    graphite {
      light = false              # only send the all* stats
      host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
      port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
      protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
      rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
      bufferSize = 8192          # Internal data buffer size, in bytes
      writePeriod = 1            # Write period, in seconds
    }
```

and influxdb.conf contains below parameters

```html
[graphite]]
  # Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true
  database = "gatling"
  # retention-policy = ""
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
  consistency-level = "one"

  # These next lines control how batching works. You should have this enabled
  # otherwise you could get dropped metrics or poor performance. Batching
  # will buffer points in memory if you have many coming in.

  # Flush if this many points get buffered
   batch-size = 5000

  # number of batches that may be pending in memory
  # batch-pending = 10

  # Flush at least this often even if we haven't hit buffer limit
  # batch-timeout = "1s"

  # UDP Read buffer size, 0 means OS default. UDP listener will fail if set above OS max.
  # udp-read-buffer = 0

  ### This string joins multiple matching 'measurement' values providing more control over the final measurement name.
   separator = "."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find free dashboards via Grafana search: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/?search=gatling

Comment: Thanks I imported one https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15046 but in simulation variable its showing blank.In query for simulation variable they have written"SELECT DISTINCT("simulation") FROM 
  (SELECT last("mean") FROM "$new"."gatling" GROUP BY "simulation"),
  (SELECT last("mean") FROM "$archive"."gatling" GROUP BY "simulation")
WHERE $timeFilter.   Now what is $new and $archive here how to set it in influxdb